# subsonic 3 | can't T.save(DataProvider ) |DataProvider is not Default|ActiveRecord

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

HI：

1. I have 2 Structure of the same DataBase,used ActiveRecord
2. IDataProvider db= SubSonic.DataProviders.ProviderFactory.GetProvide(connectionStringName);
3. db is not default IDataProvider.
4. When "T.Save(db);"  Throw Exception .
5. Message: typeof(T).name+"s" of no avail
6. When I change to default DataProvide.   T.save();  That's OK!!
7. subsonic.Core  Clone from Git yesterday！

For example:

1. class Tb_test ; ActiveRecord
2. Tb_test.save(db); not default IDataProvider.
3. Throw exception; message: Tb_tests of no avail

I find it difficult to understand！！ Please help ！！

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following as a work around.  If you wanted to pass in the provider get it this way.

Tb_test.save( new testDB().Provider );

Just replace "testDB" with whatever line you had in your settings.ttinclude file like this:
const string DatabaseName = "test";